# executeUpdate exhaust results

Tags: java, sql, database

When i try to do this, i have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Ensemble de résultats épuisé
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:511)
    at e_commerce.SQL.methodeAjoutProduit(SQL.java:42)
    at e_commerce.FenetreMere.main(FenetreMere.java:27)
```

ensemble de résultats épuisés means exhaust results group i think in english

```
public static void methodeAjoutProduit(Connexion parConnexion,int parQuantité,String parNomProduit,String parIdClient) throws SQLException{
            Connexion connexion = parConnexion;
            Statement stmt = connexion.getConnexion().createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select ID_PRODUIT FROM PRODUIT where NOM_PRODUIT='"+parNomProduit+"'");
            ResultSet rset2 = stmt.executeQuery("select ID_PANIER FROM PANIER,CLIENT where CLIENT.ID_CLIENT=PANIER.ID_CLIENT AND CLIENT.IDENTIFIANT='"+parIdClient+"'");
            rset.next();
            rset2.next();
            System.out.println(rset2.getInt(1));
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into CONTIENT values("+parQuantité+","+rset.getInt(1)+","+rset2.getInt(2)+"'");
            stmt.close();
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please translate the error message

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Something along the lines of "Result set depleted"

Comment: @Jens i said Ensemble de réultats épuisés -> exhaust results group but not sure,not very good in english

Comment: `rset2.getInt(2)` should fail, you only have one column in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurse here `rset2.getInt(2)`.

you try to get the second column from rset2 but you only select one column.

Think you have to switch to `rset2.getInt(1)` but not sure about what you trying to do.

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("insert into CONTIENT values("+parQuantité+","+rset.getInt(1)+","+rset2.getInt(1)+"'");
```

Also as i suggested in my comment, use prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: thank you, i looked about repared Statements and it runs very well